# Visual Studio Code first level embed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vs-color-theme-editor

**Hi friends, thank for help.
I'm not very used to stackoverflow. Sorry if my post is not compliant.**

I am looking for an option in visual studio code that would allow me to see the **first level embed**, of function with a line color.

There is a parameter that allows to do this, or a plugin?
I would love to have that opportunity.
It was available in Notepad ++.

I make a screen shot to help understand.
Look at the red arrow.
I would like something similar.
Show a embed red line to all firsts levels functions.
[image]

exists an extension, plugin or parameter in vcs to do this.?
Thank a lot guy for help me .

Otherwise, it would be a great request. :)

Comment: Asking us to find or recommend an extension or plugin is off-topic, which is clearly stated in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: hi in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/
 they said to go here on stackoverflow ??

Comment: For problems or questions about using Visual Studio Code, not for asking about finding extensions or plugins. It doesn't matter what another site says you should do. Your post has to meet the guidelines here, and those guidelines say you cannot ask us to find or recommend anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This settings achieves something similar.

```
"editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
```

Which will create lines that mark indentation:

[image: code with indent guides]

Comment: OMG thank a lots my friend.
its work and is very similare from what i need.